# AngularJS on nginx in Docker container

Tags: angularjs, nginx, docker, npm

We have an app written in Angular

We will use an nginx container to host the angular 
but the problem is where we have to perform the `npm install` for creating the /dist folder in angular.
Do we have to perform it in the dockerfile of our nginx-webserver or is this against the rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are obviously using node as your dev server and want to use NGINX as your prod server? We have a similar setup

this is how we do it ...

in our dev environment, we have /dist on .gitignore

on a push to git we have a Jenkins job that does a build (this does the npm install inside a Jenkins build server)

on a successful Jenkins job we do a docker build (a downstream job), the docker build copies the /dist files into the docker image

we then do a docker push

the resulting docker image can be pulled from any server - hope that helps

would welcome your thoughts :)

PS The problem with doing the npm install during the docker build is that your docker container becomes messy. You end up installing loads of software inside it just for setup purposes.

All you really want in your docker image is NGINX serving up your build files.

This is why we do not do an npm install during the docker build.

Comment: A comment from our resident expert ... if you are building a production image then you want as little as possible installed inside it - hence the Jenkins job outside of docker

Comment: How do you copy your /dist to the image?

Comment: Will it be an issue when your Jenkins is also running in Docker?

Comment: no its not an issue - conceptually you could do ... ONE Jenkins docker container ... ONE Jenkins build slave docker container ... Here the build slave would need docker installed ... This would require docker being installed within a docker container - WHICH THANKFULLY IS VALID :)

Comment: Thanks. can you maybe give an example of how your folders and files are stored in your repository. So it's possible to have 2 dockerfiles in it. (for example first: /angular and /nodejs. than /anguler/dockerfile and /angular/stuff. /nodejs/dockerfile and  /nodejs/package.json and /nodejs/index.js

Comment: + what are you doing to link the nginx container with the nodejs container? Just the --link command or did you change the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Comment: we dont have a dockerfile for nodejs - nodejs is used to serve angular in development environment using live reload, etc - in production we have nginx serving angular so only the build files and nginx make it into the docker container (nginx is not used in dev environment) - angular does not need a dockerfile - angular is a script included in the HTML files served

Comment: don't you need nodejs to transmit data from your backend to the frontend?

Comment: to link 2 containers just use --link and ensure the the right ports are exposed - i suggest you ask a new question about how to best approach your setup if you have further questions on this :)